# <ons-dialog>コンポーネントで戻り値を指定したい

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui

よろしくお願い致します。
`<ons-dialog>`の`ons.notification.fonfirm`を使用しています。
下記のようなコードを書きました。

```
function showDialog(message) {
    ons.notification.confirm({
        title: "確認",
        message: message,
        buttonLabels: [ "いいえ", "はい"],
        //primaryButtonIndex: 1,
        cancelable: true,
        callback: function(index) {

                return index;

        }
    })
}

var result = showDialog("アプリを開始します、よろしいですか？");

if(result) {

    //処理A

}
```

`function showDialog()`からの戻り値を参照して、
処理Aを実行するロジックを書きたいのですが、
`function showDialog()`の`callback`から`return`で戻り値を拾えません。
ダイアログは正常に表示され、動作しています。

どなたかご教授頂ければ幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

functionの引数にコールバックで実行したい処理を渡す方法はどうですか？

```
function showDialog(message, callback) {
    ons.notification.confirm({
        title: "確認",
        message: message,
        buttonLabels: [ "いいえ", "はい"],
        //primaryButtonIndex: 1,
        cancelable: true,
        callback: function(index) {
          if (index) {
            callback();
          }
        }
    })
}

showDialog(
  "アプリを開始します、よろしいですか？",
  function() {
    //処理A
  }
);
```